# How many days does SQL define a year interval?

Tags: sql, timestamp, intervals

Query:

```
SELECT 
      CAST ('2010-12-13' AS TIMESTAMP) - CAST ('2007-01-01' AS TIMESTAMP) <= INTERVAL '4 years',
      CAST ('2010-12-13' AS TIMESTAMP) <= CAST ('2007-01-01' AS TIMESTAMP) + INTERVAL '4 years',
      CAST ('2010-12-13' AS TIMESTAMP) - CAST ('2008-01-01' AS TIMESTAMP) <= INTERVAL '3 years',
      CAST ('2010-12-13' AS TIMESTAMP) <= CAST ('2008-01-01' AS TIMESTAMP) + INTERVAL '3 years'
```

Result: false   true    true    true

Why the 1st column CAST ('2010-12-13' AS TIMESTAMP) - CAST ('2007-01-01' AS TIMESTAMP) <= INTERVAL '4 years' returns FALSE??

Comment: What SQL engine are you using? Also, `TIMESTAMP` doesn't seem like the correct way to do this. You should probably use the `DATEDIFF` function or whatever is equivalent for your SQL engine.

Comment: I use PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figure it out. Interval ‘1 year’ includes only 360 days.

- Column 1: left = 1442 days, right = 360 * 4 = 1440 days —> return false
- Column 2: in the right expression, 2007 (year part of 2007-01-01) +  4 (the 4 year interval) = 2011 —> right = ‘2011-01-01’
- Column 3: left = 1077 days, right = 360 * 3 = 1080 days —> return true